# Exclude default routes form index.js file in Express.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express app where structure goes like this

```
server/
  |---/model
  |---/routes
  |---/controllers
  |---index.js
```

In my `index.js` file I'm handling default route for `item`

```
//index.js
const item = require('./routes/item');
const app = express();

// Endpoint for all operations related with /item
app.use('/item', item);
```

In routes directory I have a file item.js

```
//item.js

const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const {
  deleteItemById,
  itemCreate,
  getItemById,
  updateItem
} = require('../controllers/item');

// Add new product
router.post('/create', itemCreate);

// Get product by id
router.get('/:id', getItemById);

// Delete product by id
router.delete('/:id/delete', deleteItemById);

// Update product by id
router.patch('/:id/update', updateItem);

module.exports = router;
```

The question is, how can I exclude line `app.use('/item', item);` to handle this route completely in routes/item.js file? 
To have something like this in item.js file:

```
router.use('/item')
router.post('foo bar')
router.get('foo bar);
```

and in my index only `require('./routes/item.js)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think you can do exactly what you want but you might be able to get close by exporting a function from `item.js`:

```
// item.js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

...

module.exports = (app) => app.use('/item', router)
```

...and then passing `app` to it in `index.js`:

```
// index.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

require('./routes/item')(app)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot! Thank you very much

Comment: No problem - happy it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I use for handling routes within modules:

```
// Init Express
const express = require ( 'express' );
const app = express ();

// Create a router (I use this approach to create multiple routers)
const apiRouter = express.Router ({});

// Include the routes module
require ( './api/v1.0/routes/item' ) ( apiRouter );


// ./api/v1.0/routes/item
module.exports = router => {

    const itemController = require ( '../controllers/test' );

    // Define routes here
    router.post ( '/items', [
        itemController.doPost
    ] );
    router.get ( '/item/:id', [
        itemController.getItem
    ] );

};
```

I create a separate router object this way so that I can create multiple routers if needed.. (one for UI app, one for API etc).

Hope this helps..